Как сделать разные цвета для username и hostname в p10k zsh?
Нагуглил только одну тему на оф. странице github, но если вставить в файл .p10k.zsh в домашнем каталоге, то ничего не меняется. Как изменить это? И если возможно, то и разделитель, то бишь - "@"
